# Why does @abstractmethod need to be used in a class whose metaclass is derived from ABCMeta?

Tags: python, inheritance, abstract-class, python-decorators, abc

[PEP 3119](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/) states that:

> The `@abstractmethod` decorator should only be used inside a class body, and only for classes whose metaclass is (derived from) `ABCMeta`. Dynamically adding abstract methods to a class, or attempting to modify the abstraction status of a method or class once it is created, are not supported.

I cannot find, however, an explanation of why that is. Specifically, I do not notice a difference in behavior when using only `@abstractmethod` in a class that does not explicitly inherit from `ABCMeta`. In the following simple example, if I understand correctly, the proper way of doing things would be:

```
import six
from abc import ABCMeta
from abc import abstractmethod

class Base(six.with_metaclass(ABCMeta)):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Init abstract base')

    @abstractmethod
    def do_something(self):
        pass

class Subclass(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Subclass, self).__init__()

    def do_something(self):
        print('Done.')

sub = Subclass()
sub.do_something()
```

However, if I let the `Base` class inherit simply from `object`, and only use the decorator when needed, I notice no change in behavior.

```
from abc import abstractmethod

class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Init abstract base')

    @abstractmethod
    def do_something(self):
        pass

class Subclass(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Subclass, self).__init__()

    def do_something(self):
        print('Done.')

sub = Subclass()
sub.do_something()
```

I have found this to be the case even on more complex architectures, so I wonder: when does the latter method fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't see any difference because your first subclass does implement the `do_something` abstractmethod.

Comment out the definition of `do_something` in the subclasses in both versions and you'll find out that in the first case you get a `TypeError` when trying to instanciate the subclass - you'd also get one trying to instanciate the first version `Base` class itself FWIW. With the second version, you can instanciate both classes (which shouldn't be possible since they are abstract) and call the abstract `do_something` method - which kind of defeats one of main points of ABCs.

You'll also miss quite a few other interesting features of ABCs FWIW...

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate a bit on other relevant features that are missed out on in this case?